# Функция R shell() не сохраняет результаты в вектор при запуске скрипта через RScript.exe?

Tags: shell, r

Скрипт `wget_test.R`:

```
print(paste0('OUT:', shell("bash -c 'wget https://www.ft.com -O out.html'", intern = TRUE)))
```

Запускаю в R Console:

```
 [1] "OUT:Will not apply HSTS. The HSTS database must be a regular and non-world-writable file."
 [2] "OUT:ERROR: could not open HSTS store at '/home/adollo/.wget-hsts'. HSTS will be disabled."
 [3] "OUT:--2019-07-18 14:58:46--  https://www.ft.com/"                                         
 [4] "OUT:Resolving www.ft.com (www.ft.com)... 151.101.246.109"                                 
 [5] "OUT:Connecting to www.ft.com (www.ft.com)|151.101.246.109|:443... connected."             
 [6] "OUT:HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK"                                       
 [7] "OUT:Length: 446829 (436K) [text/html]"                                                    
 [8] "OUT:Saving to: вЂ\u0098out.htmlвЂ™"                                                       
 [9] "OUT:"                                                                                     
[10] "OUT:     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 11%  851K 0s"          
[11] "OUT:    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 22% 1.65M 0s"          
[12] "OUT:   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 34% 47.7M 0s"          
[13] "OUT:   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 45% 51.5M 0s"          
[14] "OUT:   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 57%  636K 0s"          
[15] "OUT:   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 68% 36.9M 0s"          
[16] "OUT:   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 80% 47.7M 0s"          
[17] "OUT:   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 91% 51.0M 0s"          
[18] "OUT:   400K .......... .......... .......... ......               100% 47.2M=0.2s"        
[19] "OUT:"                                                                                     
[20] "OUT:2019-07-18 14:58:46 (2.46 MB/s) - вЂ\u0098out.htmlвЂ™ saved [446829/446829]"          
[21] "OUT:"
```

Запускаю в терминале Windows `RScript wget_test.R`:

```
Will not apply HSTS. The HSTS database must be a regular and non-world-writable file.
ERROR: could not open HSTS store at '/home/adollo/.wget-hsts'. HSTS will be disabled.
--2019-07-18 14:59:03--  https://www.ft.com/
Resolving www.ft.com (www.ft.com)... 151.101.246.109
Connecting to www.ft.com (www.ft.com)|151.101.246.109|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 446759 (436K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘out.html’

out.html                      100%[=================================================>] 436.29K  --.-KB/s    in 0.1s

2019-07-18 14:59:03 (3.07 MB/s) - ‘out.html’ saved [446759/446759]

[1] "OUT:"
```

Пробовал также функцию system - результаты такие же.

В чём может быть причина разницы в результатах?

`sessionInfo()` в R Console:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251    LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rvest_0.3.4 xml2_1.2.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.0     compiler_3.6.0 selectr_0.4-1  magrittr_1.5   R6_2.4.0       tools_3.6.0    curl_3.3       Rcpp_1.0.1     stringi_1.4.3 
[10] stringr_1.4.0
```

`sessionInfo()` через RScript.exe:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251 [3] LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C [5] LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251

attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] compiler_3.6.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообще программа *wget* пишет сообщения в стандартный поток ошибок (*stderr*). надо всего лишь его перенаправить туда же, куда и стандартный поток вывода (*stdout*).

сравните:

```
> print(paste0('out:',system('wget -O y.html http://ya.ru',intern=T)))
--2019-07-19 01:18:15--  http://ya.ru/
Resolving ya.ru (ya.ru)... 87.250.250.242, 2a02:6b8::2:242
Connecting to ya.ru (ya.ru)|87.250.250.242|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://ya.ru/ [following]
--2019-07-19 01:18:15--  https://ya.ru/
Connecting to ya.ru (ya.ru)|87.250.250.242|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 Ok
Length: 13607 (13K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘y.html’

y.html              100%[===================>]  13.29K  --.-KB/s    in 0.02s

2019-07-19 01:18:15 (768 KB/s) - ‘y.html’ saved [13607/13607]

[1] "out:"
```

и так:

```
> print(paste0('out:',system('wget -O y.html http://ya.ru 2>&1',intern=T)))
 [1] "out:--2019-07-19 01:18:32--  http://ya.ru/"
 [2] "out:Resolving ya.ru (ya.ru)... 87.250.250.242, 2a02:6b8::2:242"
 [3] "out:Connecting to ya.ru (ya.ru)|87.250.250.242|:80... connected."
 [4] "out:HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found"
 [5] "out:Location: https://ya.ru/ [following]"
 [6] "out:--2019-07-19 01:18:32--  https://ya.ru/"
 [7] "out:Connecting to ya.ru (ya.ru)|87.250.250.242|:443... connected."
 [8] "out:HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 Ok"
 [9] "out:Length: 13610 (13K) [text/html]"
[10] "out:Saving to: ‘y.html’"
[11] "out:"
[12] "out:     0K .......... ...                                        100%  714K=0.02s"
[13] "out:"
[14] "out:2019-07-19 01:18:32 (714 KB/s) - ‘y.html’ saved [13610/13610]"
[15] "out:"
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А то я уже решил, что R полон багов, и успел "поправить" код функции system :)